# Python 2.7 mmap write hex value

Tags: python-2.7, hex, mmap

I have file loaded in memorry inside mmap variable.
Now what i want to do is to change value of location, but i want to write it in hex and got no idea how to do it. In memorry when i try to read it it some strange symbol and I can read it in hex using

```
binascii.hexlify(mapedit[80023])
```

but i got no idea how to write to that location my hex value. Trying

```
binascii.hexlify(mapedit[80023]) = 0x02
```

gives me error "*** can't assign to function call"

Can anyone please explain to me how to write it please?

Comment: what you are doing is like `id(some_variable)=new_adress` which will return the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, cos I am dumb as brick I didnt notice function unhelify, now I solved my problem using it. Code for someone who encounters same problem:

```
editVar = binascii.unhexlify("00")
mapedit[80023] = editVar
```